# How To Convert Free Heroku Django To Paid App

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, free

Some time ago I created my first training Python Django Web application on Heroku because I could do it for free. It is a typical CRUD application with a persistent database.

I have enjoyed showing it to others since then. I just received notice from Heroku that I need to convert it to a paid application. I having indeed spent hours pouring over the documentation cited about the conversion, but I am still confused about what exactly I need to do.

I believe that the best path is to change the dyno status from "free" to "eco".
That would cost only $5 a month. I am not sure about the database. Is that included, or would that need also to be converted to a paid "mini" postgres for an additional $5 a month?

And would I have to do all the data conversion work manually, or does that happen automatically behind the scenes?

Answers to these questions are key to understand if Heroku will still be a home for my application, or will I need to move it to another platform.
Thank you.

Comment: you can do it on aws ec2 for 1 year for Free if you're good with SQLIte.